# <svg> <use> only displays in positive quadrant?

Tags: svg

Failing to understand why only one quadrant is showing red color rather than the entire viewable area of the SVG? The same rect outside of use covers the entire area, what am I missing?

```css
svg {
  height: 50vmin;
  border: solid 1px black;
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="quadrant">
      <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="#f00"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="#0f0"/>
  <use xlink:href="#quadrant" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use element doesn't have x or y attributes so it starts at 0,0 and not -1, -1 as the prior rect does.

The symbol doesn't have a viewBox so the symbol displays from 0, 0 to 100%, 100% i.e. 1, 1 (since that's where the root viewBox says 100% maps to).

```css
svg {
  height: 50vmin;
  border: solid 1px black;
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="quadrant" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
      <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="#f00"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="2" height="2" fill="#0f0"/>
  <use x="-1" y="-1" xlink:href="#quadrant" />
</svg>
```

The alternative would be to just make the symbol's overflow: visible but I wouldn't recommend it as overflow: visible has terrible performance.

Comment: I understand the portion regarding the viewBox. However, x and y I'm finding confusing. The way I'm thinking of it x and y should be 0 and the <use> element should be displaying in its original location. However, it seems as though x and y on a use element map to the upper left corner of the svg?

Comment: The rect just before the use is at -1, -1 so why is it a surprise that you'd put the use in the same place by using the same values?